# Visual Studio Nuget Restore no Path in Reference Properties

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

Good Morning,
Super weird quirk that I have ran into and is repeatable on multiple machines.

We have an internal nuget repo. When I delete the packages folder and all of the bin/obj folders from my project then restore nuget packages several things happen:

1. The nuget packages get downloaded successfully
2. Only 3 of the packages fail their reference on 2 of the projects in the solution
3. When I right click on one of the failed references and go to properties, 2 of the references get fixed.
4. When I right click on the last failed reference, it shows no Path information.
5. When I uninstall that nuget package, then reinstall on those projects from the exact same source, everything works just fine.

So, I have no idea what is going on. The 2 references that restore after opening the properties panel come from nuget.org. The 1 reference that doesn't restore comes from our internal nuget repo. But none of that should matter since the nuget packages get pulled down correctly. It seems to just be something within Visual Studio 2019 that doesn't set the reference data/path correctly within the projects when the nuget packages are restored.

Any ideas on how to fix permanently so other devs don't have this issue??

Thanks for any help!

** a little bit of followup. After uninstalling/reinstalling of the nuget package, the reference properties correctly show Copy Local as true, Specific Version as true, and the other information including path is correctly filled out.

Comment: do you use old packages.config based or new PackageReference Include to nuget packages?

Comment: It is using the packages.config file. I didn't know there was a different way. It's an old legacy app and still being built on a 2015 tfs build server. Not sure how compatible the new Package Reference would be...